# Visual studio 2017 Intellisense error

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, intellisense

I am getting this warning on a new project.

> "Undefined complexType 'java.lang.Object' is used as a base for complex type extension."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android:orientation="vertical">
<android:layout_width="match_parent">
<android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Have schemas android-layout-xml.xsd, schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd, schemas.android.com.apk.red.auto.xsd, schemas.android.com.tools.xsd

Any ideas as to why I only get items showing up if I remove LinearLayout?

If I put anything inside a layout it wont show any intellisense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That xml doesnt look right, try the below. I've also added a button so you can see an example content item.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for answer I try your xml code  but no change.